# how to use the data stored in mysql table into r formulae like lm() in python?

Tags: python, mysql, r, rpy2

I am trying to find vif value before fitting the logistic regression model in python using rpy2. My data is residing in the mysql data base. The problem I am facing how to use that in r function. This is what I am trying to replicate in python

```
library(car)
vif_result <- vif(lm(target~var1+var2+var3+var4+var5+var6+var7+var8+var9+var10, data=modeldata))
```

My code

```
from rpy2 import robjects as ro
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="***", passwd="***")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("use python")
q= "select identifier,target,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10 from test"
cur.execute(q)
testdata=cur.fetchall()
ro.r.library('car')
vif=ro.r["vif"]
lm=ro.r["lm"]
mydata= ro.r["data.frame"]
modeldata=mydata(testdata)
```

Now this is throwing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#54>", line 1, in <module>
test= ro.r['as.data.frame'](testdata)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 86, in __call__
return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 31, in __call__
new_args = [conversion.py2ri(a) for a in args]
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 134, in       default_py2ri
raise(ValueError("Nothing can be done for the type %s at the moment." %(type(o))))
```

ValueError: Nothing can be done for the type  at the moment.

I want to use the data stotred in tuple testdata in the following formulae. But I am not able to convert the data extracted from mysql query into  robject or data frame .

```
formula=ro.Formula(target~var1+var2+var3+var4+var5+var6+var7+var8+var9+var10, data=modeldata)
vif_result=vif(lm(formula))
```

One approach that I am testing is to convery each field into list and then convert into data frame to be used in R. But that approach will take lot of computational time. There must be a better way to achieve this. I tried finding resource on rpy2 but couldn't find anything good other than rpy2 documentation.

Any help is very much appreciated

Thanks in advance